# How to use JS animations for H1 titles without impacting Google search results

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, animation, vuejs3

I'm facing a challenge with an animated H1 title on my single page web app and would love to get your insights. We're using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the animation, where parts of the title text are dynamically shown and hidden. Here's a simplified version of our current code structure:

```
<h1>
  <div>
    <span class="inline">{{$t("The ")}}</span>
    <span class="fakeSwitchWord inline" v-show="!this.wordsReady">{{ $t('Easiest') }}</span>
    <span class="switchWord"></span>
    <span class="switchWord"></span>
    <span class="switchWord"></span>
    <br class="d-none- d-lg-block">
    <span>{{$t(" Way to Run a Giveaway")}}.</span>
  </div>
</h1>
```

Vue3 component:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            words: [],
            wordArray: [],
            originals: {
                'en': [
                    'Easiest',
                    'Smoothest',
                    'Fastest'
                ]
            },
            currentWord: 0,
            wordInterval: null,
            loaded: false,
            wordsReady: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeWord() {
            if(!this.loaded) return;
            var cw = this.wordArray[this.currentWord];
            var nw = this.currentWord == this.words.length-1 ? this.wordArray[0] : this.wordArray[this.currentWord+1];
            for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
                this.animateLetterOut(cw, i);
            }
            
            for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
                nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
                nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
                this.animateLetterIn(nw, i);
            }
            
            this.currentWord = (this.currentWord == this.wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : this.currentWord+1;
        },
        animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    cw[i].className = 'letter out';
            }, i*80);
        },
        animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    nw[i].className = 'letter in';
            }, 340+(i*80));
        },
        splitLetters(word) {
            var content = word.innerHTML;
            word.innerHTML = '';
            var letters = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                var letter = document.createElement('span');
                letter.className = 'letter';
                letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
                word.appendChild(letter);
                letters.push(letter);
            }
            
            this.wordArray.push(letters);
        },
        resetWords() {
            var localeToUse = 'en';
            for (var i = 0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
                if(i != this.currentWord) this.words[i].style.opacity = 0;
                this.words[i].innerHTML = this.originals[localeToUse][i];
            }
        },
        mount() {
            this.words = document.getElementsByClassName('switchWord');
            this.resetWords();
            this.words[this.currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
                this.splitLetters(this.words[i]);
            }
            this.loaded = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.changeWord();
                this.wordInterval = setInterval(this.changeWord, 4000);
            }, 1000);
        },
        unmount() {
            this.loaded = false;
            this.resetWords();
            this.words = [];
            this.wordArray = [];
            this.currentWord = 0;
            clearInterval(this.wordInterval);
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.wordsReady = true;
        this.mount();
    },
    beforeUnmount() {
        this.unmount();
    }
}
```

CSS styling:

```
.switchWord {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 8px;
  color: var(--primaryColor);
}
```

The animation works as intended visually, but we've encountered an SEO issue. Our SEO checker tool interprets the H1 title as

> 'The EasiestEasiestSmoothestFastest Way to Run a Giveaway.'

This is obviously not ideal since we want it to be read as

> 'The Easiest Way to Run a Giveaway.'

I'm looking for a way to keep the animation effect while ensuring that search engines correctly interpret the H1 title. How can we structure or modify our HTML/CSS/JS to achieve this? Any insights, particularly those related to maintaining SEO friendliness while using animations, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!

We've tried a couple of things to fix this, but no luck yet:

- We added a delay to start the animation about 1 second later, hoping it would help. Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference.
- We thought about using a hidden H1 tag for the correct title and showing the animation in another tag. But, we know Google doesn't like hidden H1 tags, so we didn't go with this.

Comment: Google SEO also takes accessibility into account. Screen readers do not just read the text but the markup. As such it will always affect the SEO rating. One way would be to hide this to screen readers and write a title that can be read by it but is hidden to normal users.

Comment: I would say that strictly speaking heading elements are expected to have phrasing content (div isn't) [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) (look at permitted content) and anyway I would stick with static content for stuff aimed at SEO. This comment is not hinting any solution but is just to highlight you are following a not reccomended practice. As also suggested by tacoshy, maybe adding an `aria-label` artribute but I'm not sure how it would be taken into account

Comment: Add `aria-hidden="true"` to your `.heroHeaderText` and add an new div with screen reader only styles (`.sr-only` in bootstrap).

Comment: @Reyno not exactly. double `<h1>` will also be hit by W3C validator and SEO rating. rather use one title that contains both.

Comment: `<div>` inside `<h1>` is invalid markup. Use `<span>` instead as a wrapper for your other SPANs

Comment: `How can we structure or modify our HTML/CSS/JS to achieve this?` - how about `<h1>The Easiest Way to Run a Giveaway</h1>`?